# Manipulação de arquivos - AJUDA

Tags: c, data-manipulation

Eu estou tentando desenvolver um código cujo objetivo é ler um arquivo de texto já existente e solicitar pro usuário um carectere, aí o programa deveria retornar pro usuário quantas vezes o carectere digitado se repete no arquivo de texto lido. Porém, o programa só me retorna a quantidade de letras existentes no arquivo e eu não consigo de jeito nenhum resolver. Se alguém puder me dar uma força, eu agradeço. Necessito resolver urgente.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    FILE *arquivo;
    char letra;
    int total = 0;
  int i, c;
    
    printf ("Digite um caracter:");
    scanf ("%c", &letra);
    
    if ((arquivo=fopen("conto.txt", "r")) != NULL)
    {   
        while((letra=fgetc(arquivo)) != EOF)
        {
            if(letra || letra == toupper(letra)) total++;
       int getc (FILE *fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    
    printf ("Existem %i letras '%i' no arquivo.\n", total, letra);
}
```

Comment: `if(letra || letra == toupper(letra))`, o primeiro termo da condição, `if (letra)`, será verdadeiro para qualquer letra, por isso ele traz o total de letras no arquivo. Você também lê a entrada no usuário na variável `letra`, mas depois usa a mesma variável para interar sobre o arquivo. Você basicamente sobrescreveu a entrada do usuário e perdeu informação. Há também uma linha de código, `int getc (FILE *fp);`, que não faz sentido algum.

Comment: Você poderia me dizer como poderia corrigir isso então? Sou iniciante e quase não manjo pra ser sincero.

Comment: Comece descrevendo a solução que quer implementar em português puro. Escrever código sem saber qual código precisa escrever é ineficiente em 99.9% dos casos. Parece-me que você tentou escrever a solução em C sem ao menos saber qual era a solução que queria fazer e isso impactou negativamente na sua lógica. Tanto que tem código que você mesmo escreveu e não soube interpretar ou justificar porque o escreveu. Isso jamais deveria acontecer.

Comment: Sim, isso eu concordo com você. Mas é justamente por ter essas dúvidas que vim recorrer a este site. Porque como eu não compreendo no que eu errei, eu procuro quem entende mais do assunto pra poder me auxiliar, e assim eu não cometo o mesmo erro novamente

Comment: Você consegue nos descrever, em texto, qual é a solução que gostaria de implementar?

Comment: Então, o programa deveria ler o arquivo- texto (conto.txt) e solicitar pro usuário digitar um carectere. Em seguida, o programa deve achar quantas vezes o carectere digitado pelo usuário se repete no arquivo-texto. Entretanto, o programa só está me retornando o valor total de caracteres que o arquivo-texto possui. Sendo sincero, eu to preso nisso e não consigo de jeito nenhum resolver

Answer (score -1):

Pela sua descrição o que deseja é:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    FILE *arquivo;
    char letra;
    int total = 0;
   int c;
    
    printf ("Digite um caracter:");
    scanf ("%c", &letra);
    
    if ((arquivo=fopen("conto.txt", "r")) != NULL)
    {   
        while((c = fgetc(arquivo)) != EOF)
        {
            if(letra == c) total++;
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    
    printf ("Existem %i letras '%c' no arquivo.\n", total, letra);
}
```

Caso não deseje diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas então use:

```
f(toupper(c) == toupper(letra)) total++;
```

Comment: Cara, é exatamente isso... Muito obrigado, de verdade. Você não sabe o quanto me ajudou. Valeu mesmo, amigo!!!